# How to update Python libraries on Amazon Redshift?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, amazon-redshift

According to Redshift's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html) some Python libraries are already included in the clusters. However, I would like to use a later version of scipy for example.

I have tried to CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_LIBRARY.html), but what happens is that my scipy-0.17 library is installed in parallel with the default scipy-0.12. As a result, when scipy is called in a udf (from scipy import...) the default one (0.12) is loaded and not the installed one (0.17).

I have also tried to load scipy-0.17 with a custom name, but this works just as a label and the library cannot be called with that.

Any ideas on how to either substitute the default scipy-0.12 version with 0.17 or at least call the 0.17 version in my udf?

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I actually gave up on it a couple of years ago. I do not know if something has changed that may resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

check out the below github repository mainted by awslabs.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-udfs/tree/master/bin/PipLibraryInstaller

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not resolve my problem of bypassing or updating the default scipy-0.12 version. 

In fact I have already managed to install scipy-0.17 as a custom library. The problem is that it is installed in a separate directory and when I use scipy in a udf the default one is called.

Comment: @Pranasas: Unfortunately not. I am still using the older library (0.12) with some undesirable consequences for my code. :(